# How can i get a string value from a datagrid cell?

Tags: c#, wpf

this is my first post. I'm new to C# WPF so i might be completely off in my thinking. I'm basically trying to create a datagrid that acts like spreadsheet so that when the user inputs a sum, eg. 10 * 10, on CellEditEnding it will show the answer in the cell like excel.

I have a 6x6 grid bound to an empty ObservableCollection and when the user types in the 10 * 10 i'm trying to take the string they entered, split it, and then use the parts to create a calculation but at the minute i cant get the string from the cell. The calculation works when i set the string directly in the code.

Any help would really be appreciated. Perhaps there is an easier way to do this.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<DataCell> spreadsheet = new ObservableCollection<DataCell>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        //Communal Spreadsheet
        InitializeComponent();

        spreadsheet.Add(new DataCell("", "", "", "", "", ""));
        spreadsheet.Add(new DataCell("", "", "", "", "", ""));
        spreadsheet.Add(new DataCell("", "", "", "", "", ""));
        spreadsheet.Add(new DataCell("", "", "", "", "", ""));
        spreadsheet.Add(new DataCell("", "", "", "", "", ""));
        spreadsheet.Add(new DataCell("", "", "", "", "", ""));
        spreadsheet.Add(new DataCell("", "", "", "", "", ""));
        spreadsheet.Add(new DataCell("", "", "", "", "", ""));

        dataGrid2.ItemsSource = spreadsheet;

}

private void dataGrid2_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        // I want to get the current cell value using the below
        // string myString = dataGrid1.CurrentItem.ToString();

        // the calculation seems to work with this when i pass it to textbox1 and set the myString Variable in the code.   
        string myString = "10 * 10";

        string[] parts = myString.Split(' ');

        int part1 = int.Parse(parts[0]);
        //    string part2 = parts[1];
        int part3 = int.Parse(parts[2]);

        int answer = part1 * part3;
        string answer2 = answer.ToString();

        // dataGrid2.CurrentItem = answer2;

        // seems to work when i pass to the below textbox instead of back to the cell above 
        textBox1.Text = answer2;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 14):

Assuming that you are editing a `DataGridTextColumn` cell ...

Use "e" which is `DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs` to your advantage like  this

```
 ((TextBox)e.EditingElement).Text
```

This will give you the typed text.

Comment: Aw Thanks a million. worked a treat! Was trying to get that working for days!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to help the gaps for my solution I needed to figure out, I'll share. For the dataGrid, I needed the cell, column, row and value to do what I wanted, but I could only get the complete old information and the isolated new cell value. And just so you know what a ControlLimit is:

```
public class ControlLimit
{
    public int ControlLimitId { get; set; }
    public string ControlLimitDesc { get; set; }
    public float ControlLimitLow { get; set; }
    public float ControlLimitHigh { get; set; }
} 

private void OnEndEdit(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    //Get the cell info, which is old, then assign the new info 
    var cellInfo = (ControlLimit)(((System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid) sender).CurrentCell).Item;
    var editingElementPram = float.Parse(((System.Windows.Controls.TextBox) e.EditingElement).Text);
    if (e.Column.Header.ToString() == "Low Limit")
        cellInfo.ControlLimitLow = editingElementPram;
    else if (e.Column.Header.ToString() == "High Limit")
        cellInfo.ControlLimitHigh = editingElementPram;
    var controlLimitId = ControlLimit.UpdateControlLimitParameters(cellInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone, I use the cell Content property in a WPF DataGridCell to get the value. Here's an example where the cell is text type:

```
    private void Cell_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = sender as DataGridCell;

        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            TextBox box = cell.Content as TextBox;
            string strEnteredText = box.Text;
        }        
    }
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)